# Android AVD Manager

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

I have an Android app for rendering PDF files using PDFRenderer using AVD Manager Android 5.0 but the application shows the following error while launching
"emulator-5554 disconnected! Cancelling 'com.example.andro_pdf_two.MainActivity activity launch'!"

Please help as to what can be the AVD config to fix this...

Comment: re-launch your AVD....

Comment: Did but all the same....

Answer (score 0):

In menu>window>show view> devices

[image: Click this button]

and click option 'reset adb'.
This restarts your ADB. So you can avoid the lengthy process of restarting your Emulator.

Comment: Already refreshed and restarted my adb but nothing seems to be working..is there any AVD configuration that might help??

Comment: I assume you know how to access adb from command prompt. There, check if device is working by running `adb devices`. If your device lists, then install your app from there using `adb -s emulator-5554 -r <your_apk_path>`

Comment: Thanx but that issue got solved by changing the AndroidManifest.xml `
   <uses-sdk 
        android:minSdkVersion="19"/>`